# Ajax jquery returns blank page

Tags: php, jquery

I have this JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
           $('#sel').change(function(){

        $.ajax({
                      type: "POST", 
                      url: "modules.php?name=TransProject_Management&file=index",
                      data: "&op=index_stat&stat="+$(this).val(),
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(data) {
                         //alert(data);
                         $("#ajax_results").html(data);
                     }
                  }); 

});
});
```

On status change i need to refresh a div without page reload. But it returns blank page. If i try alert the result on success, i get the response, also i checked with inspect element, its ok. The problem is that it returns blank page.

The file i'm working on, is the same( modules.php?name=TransProject_Management&file=index ) i called in ajax.

the html:

```
<body>
//...
<div id="ajax_results">
//.....
//somewhere here is the select option <select id="sel">......</select>
//.....
</div>
</body>
```

Any help, would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you use FireBug or smth similar? What does ajax return? +Make `data` more readable like `data: [op:'index_stat', stat:$(this).val()]` which is you `$_POST` data in your modules.php

Comment: I used inspect element of Google Chrome. After success, the page is blank but if i try `alert(data)`instead of `.html(data)`, it displayes the correct response.

Comment: The post is correct, it posts the data, but doesn't displaye the response to screen, i got blank page.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(data);` in the `success` callback, and print output here?

Comment: I did it, it returns me the result (correctly) in the console. - the same as when i tried alert the response. But i got blank page

Comment: Can you still output your return here?

Comment: I's long content, i can't write it all here: it displayes the page content begining with <html...... and of of it

Comment: In your PHP code are you returning json by storing your response in an array and using the PHP json_encode() function? Should look something like this:

echo json_encode(array($your_response));

If it is HTML you are returning, that is the best way to do it.

Comment: that would be your problem. Javascript will fail at displaying HTML once it encounters a line break in the string.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe is that, i was thinking about it, but don't know how can i use json in my case. I'll try smth

Comment: @Eric, that is not true, jQuery knows perfectly how to output html! `$("#ajax_results").html(data);` should work.

Comment: @Glavić that may be, but clearly the html as printed in Rakela's PHP is not being properly escaped, as it won't output as html when returned to jQuery through the ajax call. json_encode is the way to go if Rakela is hoping to print any HTML from PHP.

Comment: @Eric, not true, he is doing something wrong, this should work perfectly.

Comment: @Glavić I have several similar scripts where I am returning HTML from PHP. If I simply echo the HTML in my PHP script and attempt to read that data from the ajax response, I get the same result as Rakela, blankness. The ajax is receiving the response, as it is reading out in the console, but it is failing at parsing it as HTML when run through the html() method. HTML CAN be perfectly displayed by jQuery, but anything more complicated with double-quotes, forward slashes, obscure entities and new lines is going to need to run through json_encode() to make it through the parser consistently.

Comment: @Eric, I outputted all kind of html's, I never had this kind of problems (with all kind of quotes, slashes and-so-on).

Comment: @Glavić, hey, it is always possible that it is something else that Rakela is doing wrong. I look forward to seeing what the ultimate solution to his problem ends up being. I only know that if I modify my script that prints HTML to just echo it, and I try to attach it to the DOM it fails, unless I bring it back as JSON, so that remains my only recommendation. Hope it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following code to return your response html:

```
echo json_encode(array($your_response));
```

Then in your javascript, you will need to reference the data as:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#ajax_results").html(data[0]);
}
```

since it is now an array.

Comment: don't know if this is the solution, but you helped, i'll try it.

Comment: @RakelaRuço, set dataType to json then (`dataType : 'json'`).

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your ajax function refers to the `jQuery XHR` object, NOT the `$('#sel')` object. Just assign it to a variable before the ajax function like `var sel = $(this)` then use it later inside the function. Try this:

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
        var sel = $(this);
        $.ajax({
                      type: "POST", 
                      url: "modules.php?name=TransProject_Management&file=index",
                      data: "&op=index_stat&stat="+sel.val(),
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(data) {
                         //alert(data);
                         $("#ajax_results").html(data);
                     }
               }); 

        });
});
```

Comment: the jquery code is correct, i can see it on debug... it passes the correct value.` $(this).val()` point to `$("sel").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, first glance the code looks good. Have you tried using Chrome debug tools? Hit F12 and check the Network tab, this will show you what is being returned. You can also debug without using an alert so you can step through to see what exactly the properties are.

Just thought, you might need to add 'd' to the data returned. Anyway, if you do what I suggested above, put a pause break on the line and run the code you will see what you need.

Comment: @ jeron - it might be doing that anyway. I often use a link to an html file in ajax calls but it only contains partial html. What you're describing is something else seperate - although it's true html should be valid :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments below the question, it seems that you are using the same script to display your page and to call in the javascript. This script seems to return a complete html page, starting with the `<html>` tag.

A page can only have one `<html>` tag and when you try to dump a complete html page inside an element in another page, that will lead to invalid html and unpredictable results.

The solution is to have your ajax script only return the necessary elements / html that needs to be inserted in `#ajax_results`, nothing more.