# AJAX login form without php redirects

Tags: php, ajax

functions.inc.php

```
function uidExists($conn, $username, $email) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_username = ? OR users_email = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
     header("location: ../home.php?error=stmtfailed");
     exit();
    }
 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 
    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
 
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){
        return $row;
         // for login
    } else {
        
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }
 
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
 }

 function loginUser($conn, $username, $password){
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if($uidExists === false){
        $response = [
            'status' => 'failed',
            'message' => '<span style="color: red;">Incorrect username or password</span>'
        ];
        echo json_encode(array($response));
    }

    $passwordHashed = $uidExists["users_password"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($password, $passwordHashed);

    if($checkPwd === false){
        $response = [
            'status' => 'failed',
            'message' => '<span style="color: red;">Incorrect username or password</span>'
        ];
        echo json_encode(array($response));
    } else if ($checkPwd === true){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["users_id"];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $uidExists["users_email"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $uidExists["users_username"];
        $_SESSION["role"] = $uidExists["users_role"];
        $_SESSION["gender"] = $uidExists["users_gender"];
        header("location: ../home.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

login.inc.php

```
<?php
 require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
 require_once 'functions.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST ["submitLog"])){
    $username = $_POST["logusername"];
    $password = $_POST["logpassword"];
    
    loginUser($conn, $username, $password);
    

} else {
    header("location: ../home.php");
    exit();
}
```

jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitLog").click(function(e) {
            
           var username = $('#logusername').val().trim();
           var password = $('#logpassword').val().trim();
           if(username != '' && password != ''){
              $.ajax({
                 url: 'includes/functions.inc.php',
                 type: 'post',
                 data: {username: username, password: password},
                 dataType: 'json', // add this
                 beforeSend: function() {    
                    $("#loadinggg_spinner").show();
                },
                 success: function(response){
                    if(response["status"] =="failed"){
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#uname_response').html(response[0]);
                        $('#uname_response').show();
                        $("#loadinggg_spinner").hide();
                          
                    }       
                 }
     
              });
           }else if(username == ''){
            $('#errorusernameLog').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
           } else {
            $('#errorpasswordLog').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(); 
           }
     
         });
     
      });
```

I only want the redirect to work whenever the person has entered correct details and can proceed to login to the website. However, when the person enters wrong username or password I want the login form to not redirect to any page, instead I just want to output a message but its not working. Where should I echo $response variable?

uidExists() is the function that looks for a specific user in the database. The function loginUser() is responsible for the login process which in turn is used in login.inc.php. I've tried changing the output of the $response variable in various places but I am only being sent to a blank page outputting the message if I enter wrong details.

Comment: anyone willing to help here? im quite lost a bit

Comment: where did you redirect when a user entered the wrong uname/pass?

Comment: @Coderio What I want is to avoid redirecting the user if the user enters wrong username or wrong password so I used the $response variable in the file functioncs.inc.php in loginUser() function where it says checkPwd === false and it sends me to a blank page outputting that message

Comment: I'm afraid it is caused by `header()`. Doesn't it redirect you to the URL?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I think your route stopped when `if($uidExists === false)` was satisfied and threw `header()` then redirected the user.

Comment: @Coderio Unfortunately does not change anything if i remove that header either, it still takes me to a blank page.

Comment: @Coderio the only redirect i want to keep is when checkPwd == true so when the details are correct the user can proceed to login and be redirected, but everything else id like ajax to take care of it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it will work:

**PHP**

```
function loginUser($conn, $username, $password){
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if($uidExists === false){
        header("location: ../home.php?error=wrongusername");
        exit();
    }

    $passwordHashed = $uidExists["users_password"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($password, $passwordHashed);

    if($checkPwd === false){
        // change to this
        $response = [
            'status' => 'failed',
            'message' => '<span style="color: red;">Incorrect username or password</span>'
        ]

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else if ($checkPwd === true){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["users_id"];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $uidExists["users_email"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $uidExists["users_username"];
        $_SESSION["role"] = $uidExists["users_role"];
        $_SESSION["gender"] = $uidExists["users_gender"];
        header("location: ../home.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

**JQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitLog").click(function(e) {
            
           var username = $('#logusername').val().trim();
           var password = $('#logpassword').val().trim();
           if(username != '' && password != ''){
              $.ajax({
                 url: 'includes/functions.inc.php',
                 type: 'post',
                 data: {username: username, password: password},
                 dataType: 'json', // add this
                 beforeSend: function() {    
                    $("#loadinggg_spinner").show();
                },
                 success: function(response){
                    if(response["status"] =="failed"){
                        $('#uname_response').html(response["message"]);
                        $('#uname_response').show();
                        $("#loadinggg_spinner").hide(); 
                    }
                 }
              });
           }else if(username == ''){
            $('#errorusernameLog').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
           } else {
            $('#errorpasswordLog').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(); 
           }
         });
     
      });
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work either, it does still take me to a blank page with the whole output of the $response array.

Comment: It should be working though. Can you do `console.log(response)` or `alert(response)` on `success: function(response)`?

Comment: Your problem is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345822/ajax-jquery-returns-blank-page) discussion

Comment: i get a blank page with this output [{"status":"failed","message":"Incorrect username or password<\/span>"}]

Comment: I've had no problems using AJAX to send data to the server when it comes to php code when it is regarding calls to the database, I just did this with the register form but I feel like the code for the login form is kind of separated all over the place, does this not have anything to do with the uidExists() function at all?